# when uploading file then laravel shows PostTooLargeException what is solution to handle this

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

when uploading file then laravel shows  PostTooLargeException what is solution to handle this

Comment: Actually when user upload the greater file size than post _max_size in php.ini then it does not go in controller for checking validation it directly goes to the postTooLargeException error page of framework

Answer (score 0):

Check the following parameters in your `php.ini` file. Your file must have a greater size than what you have set for these parameters in your `php.ini` file.

- max_file_size
- upload_max_filesize
- post_max_size

Comment: I want solution PostTooLargeException handling without changing the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes on your `php.ini` file.

Just set `max_file_size`,`upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to a higher value maybe `40M` or as much you want.

Comment: I want solution PostTooLargeException handling without changing the php.ini

Comment: what is bad about changing php.ini ?

Comment: Actually when user upload the greater file size than post _max_size in php.ini then it does not go in controller for checking validation it directly goes to the postTooLargeException error page of framework

Answer (score 0):

Update your `php.ini` file with below variable:

```
max_file_size
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
```

Comment: I want solution PostTooLargeException handling without changing the php.ini

Comment: @satish: Or you put validation for max file size

Answer (score 0):

For temporary basis you can disable this check by visiting ***ValidatePostSize.php***

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
 //       if ($request->server('CONTENT_LENGTH') > $this->getPostMaxSize()) 
             {
                 //            throw new PostTooLargeException;
   //        }

    return $next($request);
}
```

OR you can handle the exception in ***App\Exceptions\handler***

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
  if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException) {
     // handle response accordingly
   }
   return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

else need to update php.ini file

```
upload_max_filesize = 10MB          //size you want
```

or we can use client side validation to check for size and validate the size
Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually when user upload the greater file size than post _max_size in php.ini then it does not go in controller for checking validation it directly goes to the postTooLargeException error page of framework

Comment: Not Working  for this       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
 //       if ($request->server('CONTENT_LENGTH') > $this->getPostMaxSize()) 
             {
                 //            throw new PostTooLargeException;
   //        }

    return $next($request);
}

Comment: Then you have 3 options to work with: 1. Handle the error in Exception handler as mentioned above. 2.Put client side validation to check for file size : $(document).on("change", "#elementId", function(e) {
      if(this.files[0].size > 7244183)
      {
        alert("The file size is too larage"); 
        document.getElementById('#elemendId').value = "";
      }
}); 3. set value in config file for file size: upload_max_filesize